# Which is the correct sentence using the word 'Let'?

Tags: grammar, sentence, contemporary-english

In the following two sentences, I think that the first one is more precisely  correct:

> (1) **Let** G be a graph with n vertices, and S be the set of all subgraphs of G.

> (2) **Let** G be a graph with n vertices, and **let** S be the set of all subgraphs of G.

Comment: They're both precisely correct according to the rules of grammar. Merely variants on a theme.  (1) displays an example of the appliance of the _conjunction reduction_  rule. Would you say "I am hot and I am weary" is 'more correct' than "I am hot and weary"? // Of course, there are occasions where deletions of any kind aree better avoided as they give rise to ambiguity or difficulty in parsing.

Comment: They are both grammatical, but the more concise (1) would perhaps be preferred by most speakers. "Let G [be a graph with n vertices], [and __ S [ be the set of all subgraphs of G]]. Syntactically, the be clauses form a coordination, each serving as second complement of "let" or gap __.

Comment: You may even use a further ellipsis and not repeat "be".

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments..